# Android AsyncTask stuck

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

**Context:**
The following AsyncTask for an android application sends and receives so called Request objects from a server.
If the user makes changes to his stuff in the app, new request objects get generated and added to the synchronization queue. If he then hits the sync-button the AsyncTask is created and executed with his requests as parameters.

The handler finally takes all answers and sets the neccessary consequences in the database. He then finally updates the UI by calling one single method on the UI thread (onPostExecute).

```java
public class RequestSender extends AsyncTask<Request, Void, Boolean>{

// Server data
private String host;
private int port = 1337;

private Socket socket;
private AnswerHandler handler;

public RequestSender(AnswerHandler handler) {
    this.host = "hostNameHere";
    this.handler = handler;
}

/**
 * This method gets started as asynchronous task when you call .run()
 * @return 
 */
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Request... requests) {
    return sendAndReceive(requests);
}

private boolean sendAndReceive(Request... requests) {
    boolean isConnected = this.initSocket();
    if(isConnected) {
        this.send(requests);
        this.waitForAnswer();
    } else {
        handler.setRequests(requests);
    }
    return isConnected;
}

/**
 * Tries to open a socket on the android device to a specified Host
 */
private boolean initSocket() {
    try {
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
        socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(sockaddr, 5000);
        return true;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Unknown Host in initSocket()");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Connection timed out");
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Tries to send a request to the server
 * @param request
 */

public void send(Request... request) {
    if(socket != null) {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeObject(request);
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't write to socket in RequestSender");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Waits for the answer from the server and reports the result in the handler
 */
private void waitForAnswer() {
    try {
        socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        Request[] answers = (Request[]) in.readObject();
        socket.close();
        handler.setRequests(answers);
    } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to open stream from server");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to read answers from server");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to read class from server");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean a) {
    handler.updateUI();
}

}
```

**Now my Problem:**
The whole thing works without any problem for a few times (It depends on the goodwill of my phone how many times), but then it seems like the task gets stuck somewhere without giving me any error message on System.err.
Restarting the app solves the problem and it works again without any problem.

I already read that AsyncTasks get executed on one single thread since Honeycomb. I set a timeout on open socket and read in, so a stuck task should terminate after this timeout.

Is there any problem with my code and could you imagine a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I face this problem and after debugging a lot and brain storming for a week I finally got the bug.

Ok lets do some homework.

**Process to send/receive data**

1. Establish a connection. Let assume `connectToServer()` is a function that physically connects the device to the server.
2. The socket/TCP part. In your case you have `doInbackground()`, in which you are calling `initSocket()` to initiate a socket connetion.

> In **real world** scenario when you request a connection to a server it takes some time, may be a one or two seconds. So you should **wait** for that time before initiating a socket connection request. If a socket request send before a connection then it goes to lock state and releases after the default time out is finished which **make it stuck**.

**Programming scenario**

```
connectToServer();

// wait for 1 or 2 second.

initSocket();
```

**Sample code**

```
    /* Function to check whether we are physically connected to the server or not */
private boolean isConnEstablished(){
    WifiInfo connInfo = mManager.getConnectionInfo();
    return mManager.isWifiEnabled() && connInfo.getNetworkId() != -1 && connInfo.getIpAddress() != 0;
}

private void initSocket() {
    boolean scanning = true;
    int tryCount = 5; // we trying for 5 times

    try {
        while (scanning && tryCount > 0) {
            try {
                if (isConnEstablished()) {
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }catch (InterruptedException e){
                        Log.e("Yo", "sleep-error");
                    }
                    tConnection = new Socket(host, port);
                    scanning = false;
                    Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Socket connection established");
                }else {
                    throw new ConnectException();
                }
            } catch (ConnectException e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "connecting again...");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getName(), "System sleep-error: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
           tryCount--;
        }

}
```